# Laravel 5.2 - Artisan Optimize - Class 'TestMakeCommand' not found

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I run my local environment on docker /w shared code volumes.
When my `Dockerfile` runs `php artisan optimize` it fails with...

```
Step 14/15 : RUN composer install && composer update
 ---> Running in 94698cafb7bf
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Package operations: 0 installs, 2 updates, 0 removals
  - Updating aws/aws-sdk-php (3.30.0 => 3.30.2): Downloading (100%)         
  - Updating barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper (v2.3.2 => v2.4.0): Downloading (100%)         
Generating autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postInstall
> php artisan optimize


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]          
  Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Console\TestMakeCommand' not found  


Script php artisan optimize handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 1
```

However, it I run locally `php artisan optimize` it works fine, and also if I remove that from `composer.json` it will build fine and I can run it on the container with no issues, I don't understand the difference why it wouldn't run when building the container?

Comment: try `composer dumpauto`  and check `$compiledPath` in the file  `bootstrap/autoload.php`

Comment: `composer dumpauto` after or before?

Comment: before trying `php artisan optimize`

Comment: Running as 3 seperate commands, getting the same error :/

Comment: did you try this too ? `php artisan clear-compiled`

Comment: get the same error when i run `php artisan clear-compiled`